# Dynamically UPDATE Variable Number of Columns with FMDB in Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, fmdb

Let's say I have an array of columns and an array of values like this:

```
let columns = ["a = ?","b = ?","c = ?"]
let values = ["one","two","three","entryId100"]
```

I have a table in my SQLite database with columns named "a", "b", and "c".

If I try to do this:

```
let columnsString = columns.joinWithSeparator(", ")
let sql = "UPDATE table SET \(columnsString) WHERE entryId = ?"
db.executeUpdate(sql, withArgumentsInArray:[values])
```

I get an error that `the bind count (1) is not correct for the # of variables in the query (4)`.

But if I print my `sql` string, it looks good:

```
UPDATE table SET a = ?, b = ?, c = ? WHERE entry = ?
```

It seems to not be recognizing my dynamically generated `column = ?` values. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: So, the obvious question, is executeUpdate doing the binding correctly? What's the *output* SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `db.executeUpdate(sql, withArgumentsInArray:values)`, not `db.executeUpdate(sql, withArgumentsInArray:[values])` (don't wrap `values` in an array)

Comment: Oh, man, I was totally chasing the wrong problem on this one. I should have caught this. Thank you!